# UI-Router Routing Back to Default

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on an application that needs to be able to change views on a click.

I have a table of values that are clickable leading to the main page for that object. I'm having an issue with my routes because no matter what my route goes back to the default ('/').

Here is my main javascript file.

```
angular.module('myApp',['ui.router', 'templates', 'angular-loading-bar'])
.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // Default route
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider

        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
            resolve: {
                    product: ['products', function(products) {
                        return products.get();
                    }]
            }
        })
        .state('schedules', {
            url:'/schedules',
            controller: 'SchedulesCtrl',
            templateUrl:'schedules/_schedules.html',
            resolve: {
                schedules: ['schedules', function(schedules) {
                    return schedules.get();
                }]
            }
    });

}]);
```

I've tried two different ways to change the page, a regular link on the navbar `<li><a href="#/schedules">Click Me</a></li>` and by adding a function an ng-click `$location.path('/schedules');` on the table. I can see the link change quickly, but it re-routes to the default.

Here's my main application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
      <title>Features</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <div ng-include="'nav/_nav.html'"></div>

        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div ui-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

HTML for Navbar partial

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-toggle">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand">My App</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-toggle">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="/">Main</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/schedules">Schedule</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                    <label for="date">Label</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="datePicker" datepicker id="date"/>
                </form>
            </div>
</nav>
```

Home Partial

```
<div class="panel panel-default ">
                <div class="panel-heading flex">

                        <span class="sg-box inline">
                            <h2>Home
                                <div class="flex inline flex-right pull-right">
                                    <form class="form-inline">
                                        <a ng-attr-class="btn btn-default btn-small {{allFilterOn && 'btn-secondary'}}" ng-click="turnOnAllFilter()">All</a>
                                        <a ng-attr-class="btn btn-default  btn-small {{missingFilterOn && 'btn-secondary'}}" ng-click="turnOnMissingFilter()">Missing</a>
                                        <a ng-attr-class="btn btn-default  btn-small {{readyFilterOn && 'btn-secondary'}}" ng-click="turnOnReadyFilter()">Ready</a>
                                        <input type="text" class=" form-control input-md" placeholder="Filter" ng-model="name">
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </h2>
                        </span>

                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-align-middle table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="name">Name&nbsp;<a ng-click="sortFields('name')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
                                <th class="delivery">Delivery</th>
                                <th class="features">Features</th>
                                <th class="warnings">Warnings</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-click="go(p)"ng-repeat="p in filteredProducts  = (product.products | filter: productName | productFilter:allFilterOn:missingFilterOn:readyFilterOn | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse)">
                                <td>{{p.name}}</td>
                                <td>Daily</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="progress">
                                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{p.listing_count}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="{{p.required_features}}" style="min-width: 2em; width: {{(100*p.listing_count/p.required_features)| number:0}}%;">
                                            {{p.listing_count}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"> 0 </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div
            </div>
```

Go Function in MainCtrl

```
$scope.go = function(product)  {

        console.log($location);
        console.log(product.id);
        $location.path('#/schedules');

    }
```

Comment: can you please create a plnkr or add some more code to inspect, btw any error in console ?

Comment: No errors in console. I see the link populate and then it goes back to the default.

Comment: what would happen if you directly move to /schedules ? otherwise you can paste your code in pastebin or plnkr to make it easy to debug

Comment: If I directly move to /schedule it defaults back to /. I will post my code on plunkr.

Comment: ok..let me know once done

Comment: better you use ui-sref instead of a href

Comment: I turned on UI-Router verbosity and it was an issue with the resolution of one of the variables.... Thank you for the help @swapnesh!

Answer (score 0):

When using the angular ui.router package, you should always stick to the state change functions provided.

So you can either use the html tag that replaces the href-tag:

```
<a ui-sref="state.name.here">Link</a>
```

Or you go with the function that can be used in the controller:

```
function Controller($scope, $state) {
    $scope.goSchedules = function() {
        $state.go('state.name.here');
    }
}
```

And use the function in an ng-click tag on an element.

---

When manually changing the URL via href-tag or the location-service, you will not only have trouble when you change the URL of a state, but also when switching between normal- and HTML5-mode (no hashtag # sign in the URL bar). Changing the URL for a state could be an issue in future when two names conflict or you want to optimize for SEO. And switching off the HTML5-mode is sometimes helpful during development, but it simply looks better in production.